# My CSS Slideshow isn't working on Firefox or IE11

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and I started tinkering with a CSS only image slideshow I found online (don't know javascript yet).

It's working perfectly with webkit browsers, but when it comes to IE11 or Firefox, it's not working at all. I've pasted the code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ye6Lv/1/

My guess is I need to do some FF/IE11 specific stuff to this chunk of CSS:

```
/* ANIMATION */
@-moz-keyframes cycle {
    0%  { top:0px; }
    4%  { top:0px; } 
    16% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
    20% { top:450px; opacity:0; z-index:0; } 
    21% { top:-450px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    92% { top:-450px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    96% { top:-450px; opacity:0; }
    100%{ top:0px; opacity:1; }
}
```

if someone could please tell me how to make this run on FF/IE11 (if possible).

Thanks.

Comment: Working fine in my Firefox! (v27.0.1) Have you turned off automatic updates?

Comment: @Oliver, running v27.0.1 too.. maybe something else on the page is messing with it..

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about the browser vendor tags, you will also need to add the official CSS implementation `@keyframes` (IE will only listen to this).

Here is your fiddle updated with the code http://jsfiddle.net/Ye6Lv/3/ (Tested working in IE11)

For example:

```
/* ANIMATION */
@-moz-keyframes cycle {
    0%  { top:0px; }
    4%  { top:0px; } 
    16% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
    20% { top:450px; opacity:0; z-index:0; } 
    21% { top:-450px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    92% { top:-450px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    96% { top:-450px; opacity:0; }
    100%{ top:0px; opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cycle {
    0%  { top:0px; }
    4%  { top:0px; } 
    16% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
    20% { top:450px; opacity:0; z-index:0; } 
    21% { top:-450px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    92% { top:-450px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    96% { top:-450px; opacity:0; }
    100%{ top:0px; opacity:1; }
}
@keyframes cycle {
    0%  { top:0px; }
    4%  { top:0px; } 
    16% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
    20% { top:450px; opacity:0; z-index:0; } 
    21% { top:-450px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
    92% { top:-450px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
    96% { top:-450px; opacity:0; }
    100%{ top:0px; opacity:1; }
}
```

And you also need to define `animation` without browser vendor tags. For example:

```
#slider li.fourthanimation {
    -moz-animation:cyclefour 75s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:cyclefour 75s linear infinite;
    animation:cyclefour 75s linear infinite; /* Define the CSS without browser vendor tag */
}
```